# drawing pictures for a php project

Tags: php, image

I have to add drawing facility to my php webpage, so that users can draw there own pictures online, someone please help me to solve this problem, thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GD library to accomplish this type of application
Visit http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php for more information

For front-end you can use java script to get the user drawing coordinates which can parse in GD library to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to look into the `canvas` element for your project; this is not something you will be able to do solely server-side (using PHP).